# Javascript - overriding inherited method in cloned library

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, overriding

Say I have a javascript class `Library1.B` which inherits `methodA` from a super class in the same library.
Suppose I want to clone `Library1` into `Library2` in order to make my own version of it, and improve it by slightly overriding `Library1.B`'s inherited `methodA`. Naively, I set out doing this:

```
/* Library 1 */
var Library1 = {};

Library1.A = function() {
    console.log("A's constructor called");
};
Library1.A.prototype.methodA = function() {
    console.log("methodA called with arguments", arguments);
    //heavy computation
};

Library1.B = function() {
    Library1.A.call(this);
    //Set a few other properties exclusive to B
};
Library1.B.prototype = Object.create(Library1.A.prototype);

/* Library 2 */
var Library2 = Library1;

Library2.B.prototype.methodA = function() {
    console.log("Before invoking methodA()");
    Library1.B.methodA.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("After invoking methodA()");
};

var o1 = new Library1.B();
o1.methodA(1, 2, 3);

var o2 = new Library2.B();
o2.methodA(4, 5, 6);
```

(JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/puposqs5/))

Expected log for the above:

> A's constructor called
>   methodA called with arguments [1, 2, 3]
>   A's constructor called
>   Before invoking methodA()
>   methodA called with arguments [4, 5, 6]
>   After invoking methodA()

Instead I get this:

> A's constructor called
>   Before invoking methodA()
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

So apparently `o1`, despite being an object constructed with `Library1.B`'s constructor (which in turn calls `Library1.A`'s constructor), already uses the overridden `methodA` from `Library2`; it then crashes on `Library1.B.methodA.apply` call, I suppose because `Library1.B` does not have its own `methodA`, but rather inherits it from `Library1.A`.
What I mean when I write `Library1.B.methodA` is actually "look up `Library1.B`'s prototypal chain until you find the definition for `methodA`, then invoke it on `this` with these `arguments`".
What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do `var Library2 = Library1`?

Comment: I see where you're getting at: I expected `Library2` to become a *copy* of `Library1` but I guess it's only becoming a reference to `Library1`, so anything called on `Library2` actually gets called on `Library1`? I'll try to edit the fiddle and see if the problem persists, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Ok, edited the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/puposqs5/1/) but still no dice: same error as before. :(

Comment: I think that LibraryX.B.methodA will find its way up to the only methodA in the program and apply would work as you intended, but that's the same methodA that you're overwriting. I'd expect a stack overflow but apparently not.

Comment: You're still not doing a deep copy. Now you have L1.A synonymous with L2.A and similarly for B. Seeing as you never talk to anything but A and B in either L, it's the same as before.

Comment: Library1.A.prototype.methodA.apply(this, arguments); would solve the error but you still need to deep copy the library if you expect library2 to do something different because library2 is a reference to library1 and mutating library2 will change library1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your fiddle like this:

```
/* Library2 */
var Library2={};

Library2.B = function () {
    console.log("L2.B's constructor starts")
    Library1.B.call(this)
    console.log("L2.B's constructor ends")
}

Library2.B.prototype.methodA = function() {
    console.log("Before invoking methodA()");
    Library1.B.prototype.methodA.apply(this, arguments); //ADDED "prototype"
    console.log("After invoking methodA()");
};
```

Now Library2 has nothing to do with 1 and we write it's members from scratch. The other difference is in your super-call of methodA: you were looking for the method in or above L1.B, which is a constructor function whose under-under-proto is Function. That constructor's prototype though (not the same as under-under-proto) is an empty object whose under-under-proto is the prototype of constructor L1.A which is where methodA lives. So there was never anything wrong with the delegation of apply. You were just looking in the constructor instead of any object in the under-under-proto chain.

Now what could be simpler than that? :^@

Comment: Thanks! Would `Library1.B.prototype.methodA` work its way up `Library1.B`'s prototypal chain even if `methodA` wasn't in `B`'s direct superclass (i.e: if it had to go up n levels `B -> A -> ... -> X`, where `X` has `methodA`)?

Comment: Well that's already the whole chain. Library1.B.prototype's under-under-proto is Library1.A.prototype, whose under-under-proto is an empty object, I think. You can print it out and check. But otherwise, yes, it keeps working up the chain.

Comment: Alright, riddle me this: what is wrong with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/puposqs5/4/) code? It's all explained in the comments, I'll issue a new question if need be but I'm out of clues as to what title I could give it

Comment: You made the anonymous constructor function on line 24. Try writing L2[prop]=function foo() {... and see if you don't get a foo. BTW, your prop variable is global which is harmless but probably unintended. I don't know how you're asking chrome what it is though so I didn't try.